# How to solve decoding while using stanford parser for Chinese text with python

Tags: python, nlp, decode, encode, stanford-nlp

I want to use Stanford Parser to parse Chinese texts with Python interface. My code is below:

```
#!~/anaconda/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from nltk.parse import stanford

parser = stanford.StanfordParser(path_to_jar='/home/stanford-parser/stanford-parser.jar', path_to_models_jar='/home/stanford-parser/stanford-parser-3.3.0-models.jar',model_path="/home/stanford-parser/chinesePCFG.ser.gz",encoding='utf8')

sentences = parser.raw_parse_sents(("我 是 中国 人。", "他 来自 美国。"))
print sentences
```

However, when I try to run this code,an decoding error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    sentences = parser.raw_parse_sents(("我 是 中国人。", "他 来自 美国。"))
  File "/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 176, in raw_parse_sents
    return self._parse_trees_output(self._execute(cmd, '\n'.join(sentences), verbose))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have no idea about why such an error occurs,since my code is edited by **utf-8** just as the second line. Could anyone please help me explain it and solve it? I really need the help from stackoverflow community.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but could it be that it expects a unicode string? Does it work if you pass in u"我 是 中国 人"?

Comment: @plamut Thanks, it works. But since I have plenty of Chinese texts. Could you please show me some methods to convert "我 是 中国 人" into u"我 是 中国 人"？I really need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser expects a unicode object (you actually told it on creation that you will be using data encoded in UTF-8. However, what you send to it as a parameter are just plain string which are basically just sequences of bytes (in Python 2.x). You can create [unicode literals](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) by prepending a string with `u`, e.g. `u"我 是 中国 人"`

```
>>> word = u"我 是 中国 人"
>>> type(word)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print word
我 是 中国 人
```

And to convert an existing plain string into a unicode object:

```
>>> word = "我 是 中国 人"
>>> type(word)
<type 'str'>
>>> unicode_word = unicode(word, encoding='utf8')
>>> type(unicode_word)
<type 'unicode'>
```

If these kind of things cause you trouble, I strongly recommend reading the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) section of the Python documentation, it will probably make the everything much more clear.

#### Bonus

To convert a plain string representing a *Unicode escape* sequence to a Unicode string, use the [`'unicode_escape'` encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings).

```
>>> type('\u6211')
<type 'str'>
>>> len('\u6211')
6
>>> converted = '\u6211'.decode('unicode_escape')
>>> type(converted)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> len(converted)
1
>>> print converted
我
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Your method is working very well. However, after parsing the sentences, the result is [Tree('ROOT', [Tree('IP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('PN', ['\u6211'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VC', ['\u662f']), ... Could you please show me how to convert such '\u6211' into a Chinese character?

Comment: Seems like `'\u6211'` is a plain string of length 6 containing a sequence of characters representing a _Unicode escape_ sequence (again, I strongly recommend reading the docs). You can _decode_ such string to a unicode character like this: `unicode_char = '\u6211'.decode('unicode_escape')`. If you now print `unicode_char`, you will see a single Chinese character.